# Android - How to pass CONSTANTLY updating integer to new activity

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. I want to pas an integer to the other. this is how i do it

```
public void gotoSecondActivity(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("myInt", myVariable);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and then i retrieve it in the onCreate function as follows

```
    var = getIntent().getIntExtra("myInt", 0);
```

This works. But it only gets the value AT THE moment when i press the button to go to next activity

However, `myVariable` is an integer that keeps updating and changing. EVEN when I am on my secondActivity, the integer should be running in background and changing.

Is there a way to constantly pass this integer?

I have even tried to make it static and read it like `var = MainActivity.myVariable;`

Comment: "myVariable is an integer that keeps updating and changing".. from where? how? do you use a timer or thread to update it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement some sort of observer pattern. Use [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), or event bus like [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [GreenRobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

update (more details):

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1'
}
```

`Event.java`

```
public class Event {
    public int value;
    public Event() {}
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Event event = new Event();

    // inside a loop
    event.value = newValue;
    EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
}
```

`SecondActivity.java`

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But more importantly, what type of value are you sending over, and how do you plan on updating it?
You should be better off using an `IntentService` or some background process.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think my variable doesn't get updated when I go to my second activity. The Main Activity COMPLETELY pauses. I do not want that to happen is there a way?

Comment: In the `MainActivity`, you need to have some process (ie thread, async task, loader etc) that does some operation on your variable, then publish the result. `SecondActivity` will be listening and will get every update.

Comment: Thank you. Although a little more detail (such as pseudo or sample code) would have been more helpful but i will search on what you've said and then decide to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define the variable at Application level and you access to it at any moment?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think my variable doesn't get updated when I go to my second activity. The Main Activity COMPLETELY pauses. I do not want that to happen is there a way?

Comment: Only one activity will be active, if you start a new intent it will pause the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution of making it static should do the trick, just be sure to not store the variable locally but always fetch it from the static field, this will be the simplest way to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think my variable doesn't get updated when I go to my second activity. The Main Activity COMPLETELY pauses. I do not want that to happen is there a way?